# How can I access localhost by hostname while running localhost squid proxy?

Tags: http, networking, iis-7, squid

I can access localhost:49250 through localhost proxy. I can access myhost:49250 with no proxy. How do I access myhost:49250 through localhost squid proxy?

Squid 2.7

Comment: please add the version of squid / piece of ACLs on your conf file

Comment: @dAm2k vanilla install...
'http_access allow localhost'
'http_port 1105'